# On the full double range std::uniform_real_distribution always returns inf

Tags: c++, c++11, random

Consider the following minimal example:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main (const int argC, char* argV[] ) {
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest(), std::numeric_limits<double>::max());
    std::random_device gen;
    std::cout << dist(gen) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the program to print basically any number in the range of `double`. However on my machine the output is always `inf`. The same is true if I replace `double` by `float`.

I can easily imagine how this can happen by a faulty implementation of `std::uniform_real_distribution`, as e.g. the length of the interval from which the numbers are drawn is not representable as a `double`. However my question is, is this indeed a bug in my standard library implementation, or did I miss some some restriction on the interval allowed by the C++ standard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the requirements for a [`uniform_real_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution/uniform_real_distribution) is that the difference between the two bounds is less than `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`. So your attempt is ill-formed.

As a workaround, you could split it into two generators, one for negative numbers and one for non-negative numbers. Randomly select one of the two generators.

Keep in mind that the upper bound of the range cannot be returned as a generated number.

Comment: @NateEldredge In N4849 (C++20 draft) the description of the constructor (section 26.6.8.2.2 paragraph 1) lists it as a requirement.

Comment: Oh, it is in C++17 as well, 26.5.8.2.2 (2).